# Will Panharmonicon entering the battlefield duplicate ETBs it triggers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Reckless Fireweaver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReckless%20Fireweaver%5d) on the battlefield, and I play a [Panharmonicon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPanharmonicon%5d), will the Fireweaver's ability trigger twice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the time Reckless Fireweaver's ability triggers, due to it being an ETB ability, Panharmonicon is already on the battlefield and will already work. **Reckless Fireweaver will trigger twice.**

Comment: Aaargh! I've been shortchanging myself T_T